# R Dataframe - Applying an expression across a time series, and outputting the result in a new dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I am learning R and have encountered an issue I've not been able to overcome/find an answer for.

I have a dataframe

```
  ID=c("a1","a1","a1","a1", 
       "a2","a2","a2","a2",
       "a3","a3","a3","a3",
       "b1","b1","b1","b1", 
       "b2","b2","b2","b2",
       "b3","b3","b3","b3"), 
  Date=c("January-19", "February-19", "March-19", "April-19", 
         "January-19", "February-19", "March-19", "April-19",
         "January-19", "February-19", "March-19", "April-19", 
         "January-19", "February-19", "March-19", "April-19", 
         "January-19", "February-19", "March-19", "April-19", 
         "January-19", "February-19", "March-19", "April-19", 
         "May-19", "June-19", "July-19", "August-19", 
         "May-19", "June-19", "July-19", "August-19",
         "May-19", "June-19", "July-19", "August-19", 
         "May-19", "June-19", "July-19", "August-19",
         "May-19", "June-19", "July-19", "August-19", 
         "May-19", "June-19", "July-19", "August-19"), 
  Value=c(1,2,5,4,7,3,9,8,9,10,44,3,15,16,17,2, 3, 22, 12, 3, 4, 44, 24, 5))
```

Column 'ID' is "character", column 'Date' is "date", and column 'Value' is "Numeric".

Based on this dataframe (df), I am trying to create a new dataframe which will show the result of an expression in one column, along with the date it refers to in another column.

E.g. For a given date in "df", I would like to find the 'Value' for a given expression '(a1 + b1) / b1', and put the result in a new dataframe, showing the single value for the date period it refers to, and applied across the 'Date' time series.

Using the "df" values and the example expression, the new dataframe would look like:

```
January-19  | 1.06
February-19 | 1.13
March-19    | 1.29 
April-19    | 3
May-19      | 1.06
June-19     | 1.13
July-19     | 1.29
```

The expressions are quite a bit more complex than the example given, but I'm not sure if that matters since what I am trying to find out is how to apply any calculation and output it against a series of dates in a new dataframe - irrespective of complexity.

Apologies if this is a simple question, and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple way to achieve that

Your sample data have more date than ID/Value so I re-write it a bit.

Both methods below assume that there only one a1 / b1 for each date.

#### Initial setup

```
library(dplyr) # for data_frame manipulation

demo_data <- tibble(ID=c("a1","a1","a1","a1", 
  "a2","a2","a2","a2",
  "a3","a3","a3","a3",
  "b1","b1","b1","b1", 
  "b2","b2","b2","b2",
  "b3","b3","b3","b3"), 
Date=c("January-19", "February-19", "March-19", "April-19", 
  "January-19", "February-19", "March-19", "April-19",
  "January-19", "February-19", "March-19", "April-19", 
  "January-19", "February-19", "March-19", "April-19", 
  "January-19", "February-19", "March-19", "April-19", 
  "January-19", "February-19", "March-19", "April-19"), 
Value=c(1,2,5,4,7,3,9,8,9,10,44,3,15,16,17,2, 3, 22, 12, 3, 4, 44, 24, 5))
```

#### Method 1

```
# using condition matching - assume that there only one a1 / b1 for each Date
demo_data %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarize(Value_cal = (Value[ID == "a1"] + Value[ID == "b1"]) / Value[ID == "b1"])
```

output

```
  Date        Value_cal
* <chr>           <dbl>
1 April-19         3   
2 February-19      1.12
3 January-19       1.07
4 March-19         1.29
```

#### Method 2

```
library(tidyr)
# using pivot wider from tidyr
demo_data %>%
  filter(ID %in% c("a1", "b1")) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = ID, values_from = Value) %>%
  mutate(Value_cal = (a1 + b1) / b1)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  Date           a1    b1 Value_cal
  <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1 January-19      1    15      1.07
2 February-19     2    16      1.12
3 March-19        5    17      1.29
4 April-19        4     2      3
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works as I expected .. I've accepted this as the answer. Out of curiosity is there a reason you stored demo_data as a tibble rather than as a dataframe?

Comment: I just personal preference. `tibble` print out nicer than default data.frame in console. Other than that, related to this example there is no technical reason to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a **base R** solution that works for all sets of IDs. This is also assuming symmetry among the entries.

The important step is to bring the data into the right order. Subsequent steps just process the entries.

Benefits of using this approach are scalable execution-time, maximum control over your data, and package independence (which is personal preference).

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), class = "factor", .Label = c("a1",
"a2", "a3", "b1", "b2", "b3")), Date = structure(c(4L, 3L, 7L,
1L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 7L,
1L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 8L, 6L, 5L,
2L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 2L), .Label = c("April-19",
"August-19", "February-19", "January-19", "July-19", "June-19",
"March-19", "May-19"), class = "factor"), Value = c(1, 2, 5,
4, 7, 3, 9, 8, 9, 10, 44, 3, 15, 16, 17, 2, 3, 22, 12, 3, 4,
44, 24, 5, 1, 2, 5, 4, 7, 3, 9, 8, 9, 10, 44, 3, 15, 16, 17,
2, 3, 22, 12, 3, 4, 44, 24, 5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-48L))
```

First, re-order your data frame:

```
df_reo <- df[ order( matrix( unlist( strsplit( as.character(df$ID), "" ) ),
                             ncol=2, byrow=T )[,2],
                     as.Date(df$Date, "%b-%d") ), ]
```

Set helper variables:

```
li <- matrix( 1:nrow(df_reo), ncol=2, byrow=T ) # helper ids for the rows
colnames(li) <- c("a","b")

ds <- as.numeric( unlist(strsplit(sort(as.character( df$ID )), "" )[nrow(df)])[2] ) # ID-sets, only for nicer formatting
```

Then do the calculation:

```
df_fin <- matrix( vapply( 1:nrow(li), function(x){
                        ( df_reo$Value[li[x,"a"]] + df_reo$Value[li[x,"b"]] ) / 
                          df_reo$Value[li[x,"b"]] }, 1.0 ), ncol=ds ) 

rownames(df_fin) <- unique(df_reo$Date)
```

```
> data.frame( df_fin )
                  X1       X2       X3
January-19  1.066667 3.333333 3.250000
February-19 1.125000 1.136364 1.227273
March-19    1.294118 1.750000 2.833333
April-19    3.000000 3.666667 1.600000
May-19      1.066667 3.333333 3.250000
June-19     1.125000 1.136364 1.227273
July-19     1.294118 1.750000 2.833333
August-19   3.000000 3.666667 1.600000
```